# Extend Intellisense for Razor Editor in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Visual Studio offers the ability to extend the Intellisense support when editing XML documents by specifying an XSD that will be used to validate the XML.

Does Visual Studio offer any such support for the Razor Editor, such that I can specify an XSD and Intellisense will offer autocomplete suggestions for these new types?

Comment: What new types exactly?

Comment: @edokan For the new types / constructs defined in the XSD.

Comment: I still do not get it. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @edokan Within the XML documents editor, it is possible to specify an XSD, that, for example, defines a new element `<child>` that is a child of an element `<parent>`. Within the XML editor, if intellisense were brought up it would then suggest inserting a `<child>` element within the `<parent>` tag. I'm looking for a similar thing for the Razor editor (to effectively modify the set of tags that it knows about - currently only html tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably work. Visual Studio uses `html_5.xsd` file to provide autocomplete. you can provide your xsd by placing it next to `html_5.xsd` (which is probably in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html`) and then editing `html_5.xsd` to include your file. A Visual Studio restart is required.

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="MyAwesomeTypes.xsd" />
```